# How can I map List<MyObject> to List<HashMap<String,Object>> with Dozer?

Tags: java, serialization, mapping, dozer

Let's say I have an object Foo which holds a list of references to object Bar:

```
public class Foo{
    String fooStr;
    List<Bar> barList;

    //get/set barList/someStr go here
}

public class Bar {
    String barStr;
}
```

**Using Dozer, assuming Bar to java.util.HashMap is a trivial mapping, how do I map instances of Foo to instances of java.util.HashMap such that the referenced instances of Bar are mapped to java.util.HashMap as well?**  That is, I want the result of the mapping to be a HashMap with key "barList" which holds an instance of ArrayList>.  Each HashMap in this list should be a mapping of Bar to HashMap.

For instance, if Foo held a single reference to Bar rather than a list, I'd do:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>Foo</class-a>
    <class-b>java.util.Map</class-b>

    <field>
        <a>bar</a>
        <b key="bar">this</b>
        <a-hint>Bar</a-hint>
        <b-hint>java.util.Map</b-hint>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

And this would produce a hashmap that'd look like this (using JSON objects to represent HashMaps):

```
{
    "fooStr" : "value of fooStr",
    {
       "barStr" : "value of barStr"
    }
}
```

But I want to know how I can express the conversion to HashMap with a list of references to Bar such that I get this:

```
{
    "fooStr" : "value of fooStr",
    "barList" : [{ "barStr" : "bar1" }, { "barStr" : "bar2" }, ...]
}
```

Answers which do not use a custom mapper are preferred, but I understand if this is the only way of achieving this behavior.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with dozer, but if I were to do this with a custom mapper I'd almost surely do it as 2 steps: convert "Foo with many Bar" to "Foo with List<Bar>" then convert to HashMap. Can you do that with dozer?

Comment: @Mark - I'm starting with "Foo with List<Bar>" in this example.  I can already convert "Foo with single Bar" to a nested HashMap -- I'm just looking for a similar level of nesting, but with a list of those nested Maps intead of a single Map.

Comment: @Ben, sorry, it seems I read the question wrong.

Comment: No worries, Mark - I probably could've written it better. ;-)

Comment: @Ben Burns This is a very confusing question, could you please update to answer: 1, How Bar is mapped to a key, value pair 2, how someStr is mapped 3, in your resulting json you have a mapping between someStr and its value, but a list of bar, this is not a map...

Comment: Apologies, Tnem.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this in a custom converter:

```
public class Foo {
    String fooStr;
    List<Bar> barList;
    ...
}

public class Bar {
    String barStr;
}

public class Target {
    String fooStr;
    Map<String, Bar> barMap;   
}


public class TestCustomConverter implements CustomConverter {

  public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class destClass, Class sourceClass) {
    if (source == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (source instanceof Foo) {
      Map<Bar> dest = null;
      // check to see if the object already exists
      if (destination == null) {
        dest = new Target();
      } else {
        dest = (Target) destination;
      }
      ((Target) dest).setFooStr(source.getFooStr());
      for(Bar : source.getBarList()) {
          ((Target) dest).getBarMap().put(bar.getBarStr(), bar);
      }
      return dest;
    } else if (source instanceof Target) {
      Foo dest = null;
      // check to see if the object already exists
      if (destination == null) {
        dest = new Foo ();
      } else {
        dest = (Foo) destination;
      }
      dest.getFoos().addAll(((Target)source).getBarMap().values());
      dest.setFooStr(((Target)source).getFooStr()):
      return dest;
    } else {
      throw new MappingException("Converter TestCustomConverter used incorrectly. Arguments passed in were:"
          + destination + " and " + source);
    }
  }
```

Warning: Code may contain bugs, but should give you the idea.